# Need help in merging three tables foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have created three tables like this,

**1.**

```
CREATE TABLE person (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
age int,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**2.**

```
CREATE TABLE address (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
city varchar(50) NOT NULL,
post_code int NOT NULL,
person_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id)
);
```

**3**

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subjects_s varchar(50) NOT NULL,
address_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address(id)
);
```

Now in tables i have some informations like this:

person

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | name   | age  |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 | Sohan  |   17 |
|  2 | Farhan |   18 |
+----+--------+------+
```

address

```
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+
| id | city  | post_code | person_id |
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Tongi |      1711 |         1 |
|  2 | Dhaka |      1230 |         2 |
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

subjects

```
+----+--------------------+------------+
| id | subjects_s         | address_id |
+----+--------------------+------------+
|  1 | Accounting Finance |          1 |
|  2 | Physics Math       |          2 |
+----+--------------------+------------+
```

Now I want to show all these data together. How can I do this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a [SQL join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) statement to combine these.

The syntax is detailed in the MySQL [join documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

With your tables, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT person.*, address.*, subjects.* 
  FROM person 
    JOIN address ON person.id = address.person_id 
    JOIN subjects ON address.id = subjects.address_id
```

Keep in mind, this example uses an inner join, which may not be the right type of join depending on the data in your tables.  I'd recommend reading the documentation I linked above for further guidance.

***Edit***:
Here is a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/33JfmQQ7xbsnUYQWMgZdNj/2) demonstrating the `JOIN` syntax above.

I understood this question to be asking how to retrieve *all* related data in the three tables.  Depending on what result we're trying to achieve it might be possible to fetch data from multiple tables using [subqueries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) rather than a `JOIN`.  For example, if we wanted to know which student(s) are taking "Physics Math", we could answer that question using subqueries.

```
SELECT person.* FROM person WHERE person.id IN 
  (SELECT person_id from address where address.id IN 
     (SELECT address_id from subjects WHERE subjects.subjects_s = "Physics Math")
  )
```

Here is a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fUMrSJMd7q8vyg6ZcfxuY/3) demonstrating the subqueries described above.

Comment: Can you explain why you use `FROM person`? Also it's OK to refer to the documentation, but still you should explain your answer, for example: Why `JOIN address`... and not `JOIN person`...?

Comment: @U.Windl a `FROM` clause is required for the `SELECT` to be syntactically valid in this case.  A `JOIN` doesn't require an explicit `FROM` though it is logically similar to a series of nested `SELECT` statements (aka subqueries).  Subqueries may be easier to understand, but `JOIN`s are typically more efficient.  The linked docs offer far more info than I could provide in a SO answer.  I'll update my answer to include the subselect, which I hope will address your comments.  Otherwise, I'd encourage you to submit a new question so the whole SO community has a chance to answer!

Comment: Actually I had posted my own question on views, but that is still unanswered. So I was looking for similar questions and answers.